# Receiving Full modified icmp packet in Linux raw socket

Tags: c++, c, linux, icmp, raw-sockets

I have a specific network card (NetFPGA) which is adding a 8 byte timestamp in the end of the ICMP Echo Reply packet (checksum is ignored). When I tried to read the packet in raw socket this way:

```
recvsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
```

I got only the IP + ICMP data without the added timestamp. 
I tried:

```
recvsock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));
```

This way I get everything and I can't bind any address.
Also tried:

```
recvsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));
```

But nothing was caught..

Any idea how can I open a raw socket which will catch only the specific ICMP echo reply packets but will not omit the added 8 byte timestamp?

Thanks
Ido

Comment: Can you try using socket() with AF_PACKET option? (See man 7 packet for details) This will help you to capture packet from L2 level, therefore chances of discarding timestamp info might go away. I'm suspecting you need to capture packet at device driver level to get timestamp info.

Comment: Yes. Only second option (socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP))) worked for me until now. But this way I have to parse all data my self and find if it is an ICMP packet which is relevant for me. I looked for better resolution of L2 packets but didn't find.

Comment: Is parsing a problem for your purpose?

Comment: I prefer not to make the parsing my self (short deadline), but I assume I will have to. I'll try doing it in the java tier around my driver with [jnetpcap](http://jnetpcap.org)

Comment: BTW, did you experience native Linux packet filtering technique?

Comment: At the end I used libpcap / JnetPCAP (for the java layer) to catch all the incoming IP packets (using TEH_P_ALL in the socket) and parsing what I need.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found apparently there is no way to catch the full packet in the raw socket and still make the socket do the filtering for you. What I had to do is opening a socket this way:

```
recvsock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));
```

For catching all the incoming IP packets and then filtering out my ICMP packets based on libpcap filtering capabilities.